# Split periods in cut-offs date

Tags: python, pandas, date

Hi I have a very large dataframe df1, with 5 columns:

- A
- B
- C
- STARTDATE
- ENDDATE

STARTDATE and ENDDATE being dates such as ENDDATE >= STARTDATE.

I want to transform df1 in df2 with 4columns:

- A
- B
- C
- CUTOFF_DATE

with Cutoff date being all last day of months between STARTDATE and ENDDATE.

I tried with a for iterrows loop which is working, but it is not enough performant, as my dataframe is very large.

Do you have a better option?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`date_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) inside a *listcomp* :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"STARTDATE": ["2018-01-09", "2023-02-16", "2021-07-20"],
     "ENDDATE": ["2018-05-20", "2023-04-27", "2021-09-30"]}
)
​
#to ensure the parsing of the two dates
df[["STARTDATE", "ENDDATE"]] = df[["STARTDATE", "ENDDATE"]].apply(pd.to_datetime)
​​
df["CUTOFF_DATE"] = [pd.date_range(start=s, end=e, freq="M", inclusive="both")
                         .date.tolist() for s, e in zip(df["STARTDATE"], df["ENDDATE"])]
```

> `"M"` stands for calendar [`MonthEnd`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.MonthEnd.html#pandas.tseries.offsets.MonthEnd).

Output :

```
print(df)

   STARTDATE    ENDDATE                                       CUTOFF_DATE
0 2018-01-09 2018-05-20  [2018-01-31, 2018-02-28, 2018-03-31, 2018-04-30]
1 2023-02-16 2023-04-27                          [2023-02-28, 2023-03-31]
2 2021-07-20 2021-09-30              [2021-07-31, 2021-08-31, 2021-09-30]
```

Comment: **NB** : If you don't need the 2 input columns, use [`pop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.pop.html) instead of `df[...]` while *zipping*.